# Where can I find a Stack Overflow Icon for my website?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I would like to have a Stack Overflow icon similar to the icons I have at the top of my site. Does Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange provide free icons or what would be an alternative to getting an icon on my site?

Comment: Stack Overflow and international sites logos are available at [stackoverflow.design](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're talking about the SO logo, you can find a higher resolution and vector version here: https://stackexchange.com/about/logos

Comment: Yeah I found it I just didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Where can I get the logo together with my rep?

Answer (score 8):

If you want a high resolution logo for *every* site then there is another way that results in high resolution, raster graphics.

Basically, all the site-specific icons are a deviation of the following URL.

> http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackexchange/img/apple-touch-icon.png

Just replace the name *stackexchange* with the name of the particular site you want to use. Tada! You now have a nice, high resolution icon. Take the following examples.

> [image: Programmers]
>   
>   [image: Unix & Linux]
>   [image: Mathematics]

> **NOTE** For meta sites you have to append meta to the main site name. For example, the
>   icon for Stack Overflow Meta would be...
>
> - http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png

Comment: you gave away our skerets.

Comment: @Jin It is my job to undermine your skerets at every turn I can. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

Here :

[Stackoverflow logo official site](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos)

[Stackoverflow logo Iconarchive.com](http://www.iconarchive.com/tag/stackoverflow)